# How To Count a Column That Has Three Different Values Inside In Laravel

Tags: laravel

hi guys i have a problem i want to count a column that has 3 values the column is result it has accepted refused and pending and I want to count each one of them on three cards is there are anyways to do so I'm using laravel 8 btw thank you for any tips

Answer (score 1):

{{ App\Models\studie::where(['councilopinion' => 'rejected'])->get()->count() }} this is what i got from your explanations

Answer (score 0):

Generally you may use some kind of conditional aggregation.  Here is a raw MySQL query which should work:

```sql
SELECT grp,
       SUM(col = 'accepted') AS num_accepted,
       SUM(col = 'refused')  AS num_refused,
       SUM(col = 'pending')  AS num_pending
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY grp;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
YourModel::groupBy('col')
->selectRaw("SUM(`col` LIKE 'value1') as value1, SUM(`col` LIKE 'value2') as value2, SUM(`col` LIKE 'value3') as value3")
->get();
```

in `SUM` you can write any condition.